# Occasionally, when I wake my laptop from suspension, I just get a black screen

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, suspend

***First, let me state that I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.*** When I wake up my laptop from sleeping, every so often I end up with a black screen and the only option I have is to force my computer to shut down. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you think Windows 10 effects Ubuntu resume? For example if you only boot and resume with Ubuntu for a couple of days does the same problem occur?

Comment: Some workarounds are to move the mouse or press a keyboard key, to close the laptop lid and open it again, to tap the power button, and to hold the power button for a while but not long enough to shut down the laptop.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I have tried all of those to avoid force-shutting off my system, but they don't work.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I didn't say that Windows 10 affects Ubuntu's sleeping; I just wanted to state that I do dual boot just in case there is a connection. I mostly use Ubuntu and I have only been using that today. It has happened twice today, so I don't think it has to do with Windows 10.

Comment: This issue has worsened over the last week. God forbid I leave any unfinished work open and put my computer to sleep because now the blank screen happens _every_ time I wake my computer up!